# How can I get change_data compare yesterday and today using python from JSON data?

Tags: python, json

I have the following code but don't know how to write the formula for change_data so I have included it in quotes below.

```
import json

with open('data.kospi', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

loaded_data = data
time_series_data = loaded_data["Time Series (Daily)"]
temp = "^KS11"
for date, date_data in time_series_data.items():
    formatted_date = date.replace("-","")
    low_data = date_data["3. low"]
    change_data = "change_date = 2020-04-02.close data- 2020-04-01.close data"
    open_data = date_data["1. open"]
    high_data = date_data["2. high"]
    close_data = date_data["4. close"]
    print("{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}".format(temp.ljust(10), formatted_date, low_data.ljust(12), change_data.ljust(12), open_data.ljust(12), high_data.ljust(12), close_data.ljust(12)))
```

Comment: `Low data

       {
         "Time Series (Daily)": {
            "2020-04-02": {
                "1. open": "1693.5300",
                "2. high": "1726.7600",
                "3. low": "1664.1300",
                "4. close": "1724.8600",
                "5. volume": "766313"
            },
            "2020-04-01": {
                "1. open": "1737.2800",
                "2. high": "1762.4399",
                "3. low": "1685.3700",
                "4. close": "1685.4600",
                "5. volume": "1243600"
            }
    }`

Comment: Based on this json which values you want to extract and how do you want to compare these values?

Comment: @makozaki
I wanna get below value every days until 2000-01-01

`[2020-04-02's "4. close" value] - [1 day ago's "4. close" value]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd
import json

with open ('data.kospi') as f:
        data = json.load(f)


time_series_data = data["Time Series (Daily)"]
temp = "^KS11"


for date, date_data in time_series_data.items():
    formatted_date = date.replace("-","")
    low_data = date_data["3. low"]
    open_data = date_data["1. open"]
    high_data = date_data["2. high"]
    close_data = date_data["4. close"]
    ydate = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() - timedelta(days=1)
    sydate = str(ydate)
    yclose = data['Time Series (Daily)'][sydate]['4. close']
    change_data = float(close_data) - float(yclose)
    cchange = str(change_data)
    data2 = "{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|{}|".format(temp.ljust(10), formatted_date, low_data.ljust(12), cchange.ljust(12), open_data.ljust(12), high_data.ljust(12), close_data.ljust(12))
    print(data2)
```

with this code is working.